# duplicating values in a certain way inside a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I am new to programming as well as python, and I have a question that I have not found an answer for on the internet. I was wondering if any of you geniuses will be able to help me out.

I have a dictionary and in the dictionary, the keys are strings and the values are lists. I was wondering if it was possible to turn this dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'a':(1, 4, 7), 'b':(2, 5, 8), 'c':(3, 6, 9)}
```

have each value duplicated once into this format so the duplicates are next to the originals:

```
dict1 = {'a':(1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7), 'b':(2, 2, 5, 5, 8, 8), 'c':(3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9)}
```

Comment: The values you have is called tuples. its different from lists. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':(1, 4, 7), 'b':(2, 5, 8), 'c':(3, 6, 9)}
>>> {x:tuple(z for z in y for _ in xrange(2)) for x,y in dict1.iteritems()}
{'a': (1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7), 'c': (3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9), 'b': (2, 2, 5, 5, 8, 8)}
>>>
```

Note however that the above code was built in Python 2.7.  If you are on Python 3.x, you will want this:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':(1, 4, 7), 'b':(2, 5, 8), 'c':(3, 6, 9)}
>>> {x:tuple(z for z in y for _ in range(2)) for x,y in dict1.items()}
{'a': (1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7), 'c': (3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9), 'b': (2, 2, 5, 5, 8, 8)}
>>>
```

Also, in both solutions, the order of the keys cannot be guaranteed.  That is just a result of the way dictionaries are implemented in Python.

Comment: @jazzpi - I was just putting up the 3.x solution. :)

Comment: this is great! but how does one go about understanding all the parts of this code?

Comment: @iCodez - woops I forgot to mentioned your username!

Comment: @user3062049 - No, I saw you.  The author of the post is always alerted to any comments.  I was getting info for you.  The code I gave uses a dictionary comprehension (I added a link in the post) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) that is inside [tuple](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#tuple).  I really recommend that you study these structures.  They are a ton faster than for-loops and truly bring out the power/beauty of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your values are tuples, not lists. The difference is subtle, but the relevant part is that tuples are not mutable

So, let's first transform what you have to a list-valued dictionary, and then solve your problem

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':(1, 4, 7), 'b':(2, 5, 8), 'c':(3, 6, 9)}
>>> dict1 = {k:list(v) for k,v in dict1.items()}
>>> dict1
{'b': [2, 5, 8], 'c': [3, 6, 9], 'a': [1, 4, 7]}
>>> answer = {k:list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(v,v))) for k,v in dict1.items()}
>>> answer
{'b': [2, 2, 5, 5, 8, 8], 'c': [3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9], 'a': [1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7]}
```